# Toggle Onclick Issue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, onclick

Simply put, I'm trying to toggle a button to make a line bold (or not).  I read a few questions here similar to this problem, but the solutions haven't helped me.  Here's my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="DrawLineDiv">
            <canvas id="DrawLineCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
            <script>
                var canvas = document.getElementById('DrawLineCanvas');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                // Use beginPath() to declare that a new path is to be drawn
                context.beginPath();

                // Place the drawing cursor at the desired point
                context.moveTo(100, 150);

                // Determine where to stop drawing
                context.lineTo(450,50);

                //Draw the line
                context.stroke();
            </script>
        </div>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById("DrawLineCanvas");
            //var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            function toggleLineBold(button) {
            var button;

            if (button == "BoldNow") {
                context.lineWidth = 15;
                context.stroke();

                document.getElementById("BoldLineButton").onclick = function(){
                    toggleLineBold('Regular');
                    };

                } else {
                context.lineWidth = 1;
                context.stroke();

                document.getElementById("BoldLineButton").onclick = function(){
                    toggleLineBold('BoldNow');
                    };
                return;
                };
            };
        </script>
        <div id="BoldLineButton" style="height:50px; width:120px; border:2px solid #6495ed; background-color:#bcd2ee; border-radius:10px; margin-left: 5px; text-align:center" onclick="toggleLineBold('BoldNow')">
        <br/>Toggle Bold Line<br/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The line changes to bold, but triggers an error in the javascript at the line trying to change the onclick event.  I know I've got something wrong, I'm just not sure what.

Thank's in advance for your assistance.

Comment: In your second script tag you forgot about quotes. `document.getElementById(DrawLineCanvas);` and `document.getElementById(BoldLineButton).onclick` should be `document.getElementById("DrawLineCanvas");` and `document.getElementById("BoldLineButton").onclick`

Comment: And you overriding `button` parameter, declaring a variable with same name in function scope.

Comment: When you get an error like "Cannot set property 'onclick' of null" related to *getElementById* it means the method returned *null*, so it didn't find the element.

Comment: @Givi—including an identifier in the formal parameter list is effectively the same as a variable declaration. Declaring it a second time is harmless (though pointless and possibly confusing).

Comment: Thank you for the help thus far.  I've implemented the changes as suggested by @Givi and the error has disappeared.  However, I still cannot get the button to toggle.  Any help on that front would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add a default value to your button. `var button = button || "BoldNow";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aVICEqUH/1/edit)**

HTML:

```
<canvas id="DrawLineCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<button id="BoldLineButton">Line size: <b>1</b></button>
```

JS:

```
var doc = document,
    canvas  = doc.querySelector('#DrawLineCanvas'),
    boldBtn = doc.querySelector('#BoldLineButton'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    size =  [1, 3, 5, 10, 15],      // use only [1, 15] if you want
    currSize = 0; // size[0] = 1    // Index pointer to get the value out of the 
                                    // size Array


function draw(){
   canvas.width = canvas.width;
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(100, 150);
   ctx.lineTo(450,50);
   ctx.lineWidth = size[currSize];  // Use currSize Array index
   ctx.stroke();
}
draw(); 

function toggleLineBold() {
   ++currSize;                      // Increase size and
   currSize %= size.length;         // loop if needed.
   boldBtn.getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML =  size[currSize];
   draw();   
}

boldBtn.addEventListener("click", toggleLineBold);
```

Comment: This is a truly elegant solution.  I will learn a lot from this example, thank you so much!